# Hide copy warnings in PHP

Tags: php

I know it's not a good practice to hide the warnings using @copy, but what other alternatives are there?

Is there any way you can make sure copy would work or not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [is_readable()](http://php.net/manual/function.is-readable.php) and [is_writable()](http://php.net/manual/function.is-writable.php) to check the status of the source and target before attempting the copy().

Comment: I see is_readable throws a Warning, isn't this the same thing ?

Comment: is_readable throws a warning that can be hidden and/or logged via appropriate php.ini configuration. The type of error that is thrown by an attempt to copy() cannot be so gracefully hidden without resorting to the suppression operator. Additionally, is_readable() and is_writable() provide information that copy() cannot.

Answer (score 2):

If you use '@' before a function you'll not the warning or the notice returned but you'll keep the result (boolean, string...).

Try this :

```
if (!@copy('srcfile', 'destfile')) {
    // something failed.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Really, you should not be displaying errors to the browser. Turn off `display_errors` in php.ini.

Then you can test if it succeeded by its boolean return value, without needing to worry about the warnings on screen.

```
if (!copy('srcfile', 'destfile')) {
  // something failed.
}
```

Comment: It's good to keep warnings on when you're developing.  Turn 'em for production use.

Comment: @Rocket I figured that was implicit. Clarified above.

Comment: Thought so too, but figured I'd throw it out there.